# Send List Email pick From

Tags: email

so I was wondering if there is a way to add a dropdown selection for the From Email on the Send List Email functionality in the CampaignMembers section.

[image]

Was basically looking for something similar to the Send Email form inside the Activity of a Contact for example.

[image]

If it's not a default functionality in Salesforce, any suggestion on how it could be added?